# Select the last n characters in a string

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
df <-data.frame(fact=c("a,bo,v", "c,b,v,d", "c"))
```

I wish to select the last two items for each row. So, Ideally I wish to have this output:

```
    fact
1    bo,v
2    v,d
3    c
```

I've tried to split the rows and then choose the last two items:

```
spl <- strsplit(as.character(df$fact), split = ",")

tail(spl[[1]], n=2)
```

But doe not give me the correct results

Comment: strsplit() is for splitting strings, you are giving it a factor not a string, thats why it throws an error.

Comment: That's right, I tried this one `spl <- strsplit(as.character(df$fact) , split = ",")` but doesn't give me the correct result. I edited the question.

Comment: check out Chirayu's answer, you need to apply the function strsplit() to the df column. In other words, you have a column of strings and now you need to split each one, apply(), lapply(), sapply() are tools to apply functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
lapply(lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$fact), split = ','), function(x) x[c(length(x)-1,length(x))]), paste, collapse = ',')
```

You split the col and then extract the n and n-1 index. Then paste them together.

You can generalise this for by doing:

```
lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$fact), split = ','), function(x) x[(length(x)-n):length(x)] )
```

where n is no of backward steps you want to take.

Using `tail` is even simpler.

```
lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$fact), split = ','), tail, n=2)
```

Comment: Great option.  Plus one.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` to loop over every element of `fact`, `split` it on basis of `,` and then select the last `n` elements using `tail`

```
n <- 2

sapply(as.character(df$fact), function(x) {
       temp = unlist(strsplit(x, ','))
       tail(temp, n)
}, USE.NAMES = F)

#[[1]]
#[1] "bo" "v" 

#[[2]]
#[1] "v" "d"

#[[3]]
#[1] "c"
```

---

A better option with `dplyr` I feel using `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(last_two = paste0(tail(unlist(strsplit(as.character(fact),",")), n), 
                                                                collapse = ","))

#     fact last_two
#   <fctr>    <chr>
#1  a,bo,v     bo,v
#2 c,b,v,d      v,d
#3       c        c
```